# Is there any limit of how many commands it can be sent to modbus controller relay?

Tags: relay, modbus

I have modbus controlled relay hooked to raspberry pi (using node-red) which depending on the condition sends "on" or "off" command every 5 seconds (24h/365d). I know that relays in general have its life cycle and have to be changed after frequent use, especially on heavy load - that's not what I am referring to.

I'm referring to relay having a limit on commands it can receive. The question comes after reading manuals of Daikin HVAC modbus modules that state max 50,000 commands (If I remember well). Is this a limitation imposed by the manufacturer in order to well buy more from them or communication becomes unreliable after passing that number or is it something else?

Comment: I use Modbus in industrial environments regularly, I've never heard of a limit on Modbus commands for a device...

Comment: The relay would definitely have an operational life limit, and 50k operations at something approaching maximum load may not be unreasonable (https://tinyurl.com/vhg5n7r).
The protocol commands (on/off) would not have any restrictions. Sending repeated commands would also have no impact on relay life expectancy (eg. on-on-on-on or off-off-off- sequences.

Comment: Maybe you can quote the manual you are referring to. I think you have misunderstood, I've never heard of such a thing either. Although I'm sure if somebody can come up with such an idiotic idea, Daikin is an excellent candidate (yes I am strongly opinionated against them, I have my own reasons for that).

Comment: http://intpre.daikineurope.com/docs/Design%20guide_Modbus%20Interface%20III_4P357732-1_2014_04-tcm478-342806.pdf

1.2 Limitations - "The number of control commands per indoor unit is limited to 7000 per year"